# Save everything for new object except ManyToMany field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-2.2

I want to save object with `ManyToMany` relation. When I submit the form, all things save except field that have `ManyToMany` relation.

These are my files:

```
#Forms.py
class ExamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = '__all__'

#Models.py
class Exam(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

#Views.py
def add_exam(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ExamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_exam = form.save(commit=False)
            new_exam.save()
            return redirect('view_exam')
    else:
        form = ExamForm()
    template = 'add_exam.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**What is wrong with these codes?**

Comment: `new_exam.save_m2m()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) explain, when you use `commit=False` the form cannot set the many-to-many relationship, because the object does not yet have an ID. So you would need to call the form's extra `save_m2m()` method:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_exam = form.save(commit=False) 
    # Add some modifications
    new_exam.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('view_exam')
```

But *there is no reason to do this here*. You should not use `commit=False` only to then save the model immediately. That is for when you want to modify the object before saving, which you're not doing here. Just save it directly:

```
   if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('view_exam')
```

Comment: Thanks It works. But what about adding some modify the object before saving ? For exmaple if I need to set `form.save(commit=False)` and add this lines: `             if 'is_allow_comments' in request.POST:
                new_exam.is_allow_comments = True
             else:
                new_exam.is_allow_comments = False  ; What I must do ? @daniel-roseman

Comment: As I said, that's when you do `form.save_m2m()` after `new_exam.save()`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).